# Active Admin - hide pagination total count message

Tags: count, pagination, customization, activeadmin

***How do I hide the "Displaying all.." message at the bottom right of the index page?***

Already tried

```
config.paginate = false
config.pagination_count = false
```

but with no luck.

Thanks

Comment: You could use CSS and do a `.pagination_information { display: none;  }` ?

Comment: Ok, that was obvious..
I thought there was some sort of switch command on AA, but the CSS thing worked!
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just for the sake of providing an answer then, you can do the trick by just hiding it with CSS:

```
.pagination_information { 
    display: none;
}
```

EDIT:

You can hide the **pagination total**, in case you have a very large database, per resource.

```
index :pagination_total => false do
    #index table
end
```

However, make sure you have the latest ActiveAdmin version, as 0.6.0 doesn't have this feature. In your `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'activeadmin', '~> 0.6.3'
```

Now that doesn't get rid of the "Display all ..." in case you disable pagination totally. There isn't an option for it in the current ActiveAdmin version (and I don't think it makes sense for them to release such feature) but if you really want to hide the pagination information for a specific resource, you can then use a simple JS script:

```
//If I have a "Customers" index table
$("#index_table_customers").parents(".paginated_collection").find(".pagination_information").hide();
```

Comment: what if I want to hide it only for certain resources? I put the CSS in resource.css.scss and then inserted `@import "resource.css.scss"` in active_admin.css.scss.... but now the CSS is being loaded application-wide...

Comment: I would suggest putting these few lines of CSS right in your active_admin.css.scss

Comment: I guess that would make it valid application-wide, i.e. for any index page of any model...which is what I don't want!
I would like to hide it only for certain models, not for others..

Comment: Look at the above edit. You have two options, and I think the one you would want to achieve exactly what you're looking for is the little JS script I proposed

Comment: As for the AA way, I updated 0.6.1 -> 0.6.3, but as you said I can't disable pagination totally and the "Display all.." at the same time.

Comment: Then you can use this JS script I guess. I think that's the only "easy" way to do it. You could look into customizing how index is renders, as explained here: http://www.activeadmin.info/docs/3-index-pages/create-an-index.html but that's definitely more time consuming :)

Comment: The CSS solution was ok too, I can't believe there's no way to define custom CSS per resource... I even tried moving active_admin.css.scss from app/assets/stylesheets to vendor/assets/stylesheets, but no luck...
The Javascript solution worked anyway! Just like the CSS, I think this Javascript is valid application-wide but it only sorts effects in the "customers" index page because of the reference to #index_table_customers
Thanks very much!!!